# Keeping dialogs on top of window, but not on top of everything

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, layout, dialog

In my WPF application I have a lot of custom dialog boxes that pop open so the user can do various things with `someDialogClass.ShowDialog()`. To make sure that the dialog stays on top of the window that called it, I add `Topmost="True"` to the `Window` tag of the dialog's XAML file. This works, but the dialog is shown over *every* window open—even other applications. This is really annoying. So is there a way to have the dialog forced to always be on top of its parent, but not necessarily on top of other applications?

Here is a simplified version of the `Window` tag of the dialogs I have (omitting all the `xmlns` stuff):

```
<Window
mc:Ignorable="d"
ShowInTaskbar="False"
Topmost="True"
WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner"
ResizeMode="NoResize"
SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"
WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You need to set the [Owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.owner(v=vs.110).aspx) of the [Dialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969773(v=vs.110).aspx)/[Window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window(v=vs.110).aspx) and it will then be on top of only that window.

For example:

```
var loginForm = new LoginForm();
loginForm.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;
var success = loginForm.ShowDialog();
```

Do not set the [TopMost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost(v=vs.110).aspx) property on the Window otherwise it will be on top of every window.

Comment: Hooray! Expected behavior! Thanks!

Comment: Application doesn't appear to have a definition called "Current".

Comment: Also even if I just use x.Owner = this; it doesn't work. ShowDialogue always puts the dialogue wherever the application window was on the screen once started, not after the window was moved.

Comment: Fixed it: frm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;

Comment: Underlying (parent) form will be available and accept user's input if you call yourForm.Show() . Perfect for tool window