# WPF Modal dialog goes in background

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have problem with an application where modal WPF dialog occasionally goes behind the main application window. This hapens when I click button on the dialog which does some processing and updates controls (through binding) in the main application window. When it goes in background - clicking anywhere in the application brings it back into foreground.

```
        var dialog = LoadDialogWindowThroughMEF();
        dialog.Owner = Application.Current != null ? Application.Current.MainWindow : null;
        dialog.ShowInTaskbar = false;
        dialog.WindowStartupLocation = WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner;
        return dialog.ShowDialog();
```

The above code shows how I open modal window. This happens very rarely.

Does anybody know what could be the problem?

Comment: see this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233182/keeping-dialogs-on-top-of-window-but-not-on-top-of-everything). Maybe if you set dialog.Topmost=true, it solve the problem.

Comment: The code I pasted above is same as what the above link suggests.

Comment: Is it possible that the `Application.Current` is `null`?

Comment: What happens inside the `LoadDialogWindowThroughMEF()` method?

Comment: What happens exactly when you click the button in the dialog window?

Comment: (1) I have added Application.Current != null only for avoiding complexity while unit testing otherwise I dont think it can be null in WPF App. I have added log to check when this issue gets surfaced.

Comment: (2) LoadDialogWindowThroughMEF creates window through MEF as shown below ServiceLocatorInstance.GetInstance<IDialogWindow>(viewContractName)

Comment: (3) When I click button on Dialog - It launches background worker thread which internally launches multiple worker threads and tasks and any of them may push requests on dispatcher to update main application control (treeview) if needed.

Comment: You should edit your question with your answers to my questions, so that others reading this post doesn't need to rely on grokking the comments. Also, what have you done to isolate this problem? Can you show us some more code? If you can provide us with code that actually runs and exhibits the problematic behavior, it will help us greatly in helping you.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure I have an answer for you, but I can share some of my thoughts:

Every time I've encountered this type of problem, it happened because the `Owner` wasn't set properly. So, I'd try to *not* set the `Owner` and see if that makes the problem reproducible. You need to be absolutely sure that `Owner` is set to the correct parent window at all times<sup>1</sup>. You might also want to check that it is the actual `MainWindow` of your application that are supposed to be the parent. I think that most of the time it is beneficial to be explicit<sup>2</sup> in your code. In this case that means that it is better to assign the known parent (maybe you have a reference to the parent somewhere that you could use), rather than relying on the `Application.Current` to provide you with that reference. Doing so will put you in control of the assignment to `Owner`. It could even make it possible to get rid of the `?:` operator since you would have the means to control the reference even during unit testing.

I also want you to make sure that the code that is actually updating the parent window doesn't in any way force focus to a specific control on the parent window, or anything like that. (As long as the correct parent is set as `Owner`, I don't see this as a likely problem.)

I hope this helps you, but I understand if it doesn't. The fact that your dialog reappears when you click the parent window disproves some (or all!) of my points...

---

<sup>1</sup> Except when running your unit tests, but that's a completely different matter.

<sup>2</sup> As in the first meaning of the word according to [wiktionary.org/wiki/explicit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/explicit), and as opposed to *implicit*.