# How to keep WPF dialog topmost only in my WinForms app?

Tags: wpf, winforms, topmost

It is [known](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6233182/keeping-dialogs-on-top-of-window-but-not-on-top-of-everything), WPF dialog needs property 'Owner' to be topmost only for the current application.

How to handle the situation if the current application is a WinForms one that has a WPF-dialog?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mhendersblog/archive/2005/10/04/476921.aspx

It can be done using WindowsInteropHelper.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Window.Topmost Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.topmost.aspx) at MSDN.

Setting `Topmost="True"` on the dialogue window should do the trick.

You *may* want to also set this in a `Window.Deactivated` and `Window.LostFocus` event handlers.